# How to install hyperledger indy-node in Linux 18.04

Tags: python-3.x, hyperledger, hyperledger-indy

I am trying to learn about using Hyperledger Indy. This is my first Hyperledger Project that I am using. My aim is to setup a few nodes and do some identity transaction between them. Here is what I have done:

1. I setup docker and followed the command given on this link on [indy-sdk github](https://github.com/hyperledger/indy-sdk/blob/master/docs/getting-started/run-getting-started.md) page. I was successfully able to see 4 nodes went up and their respective directories were created with genesis folder, transaction folder, config folder etc.I was able to understand the walkthrough example and went through the jupyter notebook code generated for different agents.
2. Now next I want to explore indy-node respository. I followed the [dev-setup instructions](https://github.com/hyperledger/indy-node/blob/master/docs/source/setup-dev.md) and successfully setup all the libraries and a python virtual environment to run tests. I got msg on linus cli line saying "**Indy-node and indy-plenum are ready for being used**" after I followed the complete instructions given on the mentoned page. I have cloned copies of indy-node and indy-plenum after following instructions.
3. Maybe I am doing something wrong or not getting the instruction flow correct, but when I follow [this link](https://github.com/hyperledger/indy-node/blob/master/docs/source/start-nodes.md) I get the following error as shown in attached image files.[image]

Please help me undertand how can I run individual nodes on my system. I tried looking online for help but hit nowhere. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Regarding the error. Did you try to install indy-plenum? Apparently the `indy-node` package has an issue. Try to install `indy-plenum` manually. `apt-get install -y indy-plenum=1.12.0~dev957`

Comment: @VladoDemcak I am trying to install `indy-plenum` but I get error listing a number of python packages that have unmet dependenciesand being broken. I tried running command `apt-get install -f ` for each package and after execution of this command it shows me the latest package. But when I again try to install plenum same error

Comment: I get these errors:  https://drive.google.com/file/d/1fE3vokMKf2Yge3wqWGLcpH-EnDcBbhmP/view?usp=sharing

Comment: if you are not going to develop something I would stay with 1.11.0 version not the latest version on master. change the `sudo add-apt-repository "deb https://repo.sovrin.org/deb xenial master"` to stable like this `sudo add-apt-repository "deb https://repo.sovrin.org/deb xenial stable"`. after that retry to install indy-node, indy-plenum and let us know.

Comment: For what it's worth, I'm having the exact same issue on a fresh Ubuntu 18.04 instance while following the official installation instructions.